# ImportError: cannot import name 'QuantumProgram' from 'qiskit'

Tags: programming, qiskit

I get below error when I run a code on spyder environment:

File `C:/MYPYTHON Programs/My Quantum Programs/Shor algo.py`, line 4, in from `qiskit import QuantumProgram`

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QuantumProgram' from 'qiskit' 
(C:\Users\gurmo\Anaconda3\envs\Qiskitenv\lib\site-packages\qiskit__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 8):

`QuantumProgram` was removed in Qiskit 0.6.0. ([Release Notes](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/releases/tag/0.6.0)) Your example code is likely for an older version. You can either install Qiskit 0.5.7, or find an [updated Shor's Algorithm example](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/terra0_7/community/algorithms/shor_algorithm.ipynb).